# PApplet memory increase..!

Tags: java, memory

I am having a fairly significant memory issue related to my `PApplet` objects. I am `destroy()`ing and `stop()`ing them appropriately, I believe, but every time I call `PApplet`, object memory continues to increase.

Any assistance in figuring out why would be appreciated.

Below is my program hierarchy:

```
// This button is component of MAIN JFRAME 
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    TechnicPicForm tech=new TechnicPicForm ();
    tech.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

```
public class TechnicPicForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {        

     private createHexMirror crm;

     /**
     * Creates new form ResultForm
     */
    public TechnicPicForm() {
        crm = new createHexMirror(12,4.3,324,45,1);
        crm.init();
        this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images/logokanat.png").getImage());

        initComponents();
        jPanel1.add(crm);
}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Generated Code
    ------------Code for Init Components------------- 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        crm.destroy();
    }                                  
}
```

---

```
import processing.pdf.*;
import processing.core.*;

public class createHexMirror extends PApplet {

   private float outC,littlePipeC,triangleLine,mirrorC ;
   private int mode;

    public createHexMirror(float outC, float littlePipeC , float triangleLine, float mirrorC , int mode) {
        this.outC= outC;
        this.littlePipeC = littlePipeC ;
        this.triangleLine= triangleLine;
        this.mirrorC = mirrorC;
        pmode = mode;
    }

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        noLoop();
        size(1000, 650);
        background(255);
    }

    public void draw() {

    ----------------SOME DRAW CODES------------------------
    }
}
```